# Monodevelop + GTK# Design Pattern

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I am just creating a simple cross platform desktop application for my personal use using Mono/C#, GTK#. Are there any  recommended UI design patterns?

Thanks,
Chirdeep

Comment: You an do Model + View/ViewModel in GTK# using the designer, or MVVM with Glade#

Comment: Hi Ian, Can you point me to any resources? Thanks

Comment: a simple mvc pattern for use with gtk# - http://www.salmonsalvo.net/blog/?p=93

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar You should probably mark that as an answer so that SO community knows that this question has been answered to your satisfaction. Thanks.

Comment: @tamaslnagy The response was added as a comment not an answer to the question. I do not see a place to mark it as an answer. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar the answer the question yourself using the info that he provided, thank him for it, and mark your answer as the answer to the question

Comment: @IanNorton links is... down ? Or is green tea a design pattern ?

Comment: @franssu ooer, that waws ages ago. I have no idea now

Answer (score 1):

You might also think about using Model-View-Presenter (MVP)/Presenter First. There a sample GTK+ application here:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/07/27/presenter-first-in-gtk-and-c-updated-for-2012/

It should be fairly easy to translate the concept to GTK#.